# Mysterious Azure Pipelines definition showing up on my github repo

Tags: github, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

A bunch of people at my company have read access to my private github repo. I use Azure Pipelines to build it.  When I push a commit, I see two build definitions run on it - one is mine. The other is one that fails, and I don't know where it came from. When I try to click through to that other build definition, I don't have permission to see that Azure devops org. So basically someone is able to make CI show as failed for all of my commits, and I don't know how to ban that build definition or figure out who is behind it, besides asking around.

To be clear, it looks like this:

[image: build definition on github]

It seems like anyone who has read access to the repo is able to add a build definition that will show up in Github. Is there any way for me to control this as an admin of the repo, besides taking away read access for random people, or a way for me to figure out who's credentials are being used for this build definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need manage permissions on the repo to do that, at least add\edit webhooks. Read is not enough to trigger builds, because nothing would trigger them. Read is probably enough to run builds manually. But you won't be able to create a build with read rights, as it will attempt to configure webhooks

you need to go to the settings>branches and remove this build from the validations and\or go to settings>webhooks and delete those webhooks. Also, you'd need to revoke permissions to create\edit webhooks for this repo.

Comment: Thanks - the only webhooks I see are for `https://dev.azure.com/myDevopsOrg`. I don't see anything relevant under Branches? The bad build is definitely not in my org so I don't know where it's coming from. There are still a bunch of people with write or admin access to the repo, but fewer than "read"...

Comment: really hard to tell whats going on, but you cant have triggered builds without webhooks, so I dont understand how is that possible. also, you cant have those PR builds wiouth branch policies

Comment: I clicked through every project in `myDevopsOrg` to confirm that the build definition is not there. When I click through to the mystery build from a commit, I go to `https://dev.azure.com/orgIdontRecognize` and I don't have permission to access it, and there is no webhook for that org. Not sure what you mean regarding branch policies, I only see "default branch" and "branch protection rules" in that tab.

Comment: under branch protection rules, there should be individual rules. so unless you have `Require status checks to pass before merging` that build(s) wouldn't be needed to merge pull request. so it wouldn't appear on pull requests